# DropDown directive using angular

Tags: angularjs

I have the following directive for a drop down menu (http://jsfiddle.net/77f4m6n5/2/):

```
<a href="#" dropdown>Open
  <ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
  </ul>
</a>
```

And the directive is the following:

```
app.directive("dropdown", dropdown);

function dropdown() {

  var dropdown = {
    link: link,
    replace: false,
    restrict: "A"
  };

  return dropdown;

  function link(scope, element, attributes) {   
    element.bind("click", function(event)   {                                                
        element.children().toggleClass("active");
   });  
  } 
}
```

Can I create such a directive but more in "an angular way"? I think I should have a directive for the link and another for the dropdown, no?

Comment: You could look into ng-click, ng-show/ng-hide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be the more angular way of doing it:

```
.directive('dropdown', function() {
  return {
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      element.bind("click", function(event)   {                                                
        element.children().toggleClass("active");
    },
    replace: false,
    restrict: 'A'
  };
});
```